# eclipse - show documentation tooltip for local variable

Tags: eclipse, annotations, tooltip, javadoc, local-variables

eclipse shows a tooltip with javadoc of a field when it's hovered anywhere in the code.

Is it possible to attach a comment or an annotation to a local variable, so that it appears as variable tooltip in it's block?

Comment: What do you mean by *local variable*?

Comment: I mean local variables defined within a method and allocated on the stack (as opposed to instance field members)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10566338/1700321.

Comment: Thanks, I just discovered eclipse DOES show local variables annotations in the tooltip... Will close this question as duplicate.