# Javadoc for **local variables** in Android Studio is shown incorrectly

Tags: android-studio, javadoc

I see the Javadocs for methods and fields OK. When the cursor goes over a reference of some method or field and I promptly press Ctrl, I see JavaDoc. When I turn on the "show quick doc on mouse move" editor setting, I see the JavaDoc on simple hovering, too. Ctrl+Q also works OK.

But for a **local variable** by all the three methods I see only the frame of the hint with the definition line. I even tried to put the comment inside the line - it is ignored. How can I see the JavaDoc written for the local variable? What is more, Android Studio differs the javadoc comment to a local from a usual one. But doesn't show it.

```
    //the code:
    /** subsums of currently checked set of banknotes, according to banknotes values*/
    long[] subSums = new long[indicesNumber];
```

And this is what I see as the Javadoc:
[image]

How can I make the Android Studio to show the local javadocs, too? Eclipse has no problems with it.

Comment: It seems that using normal comments and useful variable names are the only ways as noted in an [answer to "Javadoc for local variables?"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10566366/1276636).

Comment: This could be a feature request and come in handy for some. :)